# How to setup cancan with activeadmin without any side effect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, activeadmin, cancan

I have an active admin code running which is as below

```
ActiveAdmin.register UserProcess, as: 'Summary' do
....
end
```

active_admin.rb -

```
config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter
config.cancan_ability_class = "Ability"
config.on_unauthorized_access = :access_denied
```

I want to block user from accessing this Summary page without actually blocking his access from UserProcess.

adding `cannot :manage, UserProcess` works for the page but then it also does not allow the user to access him other pages.

Also my namespace is `:actadmin`

Please let me know the correct thing to write in Ability class

Comment: I'd take a look at Pundit over cancan. Both are great but I find Pundit to be easier to apply in situations you need more granular control.

Comment: @bkunzi01 -  I would like to go with cacancan at this point

Comment: No problem.  If you repost it for Pundit I can help you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar thing by creating a custom page and apply cancan ability on that page.Otherwise ability was applied on resource.

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Summary" do
 menu parent: "UserProcess", label: "Summary"
  content title: "Summary" do
   .......
   .......
  end
end
```

and apply ability on it this way:

```
class Ability
 include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(users)
   can :manage UserProcess
   cannot :manage, ActiveAdmin::Page, name: "Summary"
  end
end
```

If you found by the time another cleaner solution,please edit me!